# What is the difference between TARGET_ARCH and TARGET_MACH variables?

Tags: makefile

I am developing project for Cortex-M4 processor and my compiler flags include this:

```
-mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4
```

Here is an excerpt from `make` database (`make -p | grep -E '^(LINK|COMPILE)\.[cosS]\ ' | sort)`):

```
COMPILE.S = $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_MACH) -c
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
COMPILE.s = $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $(TARGET_MACH)
LINK.S = $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_MACH)
LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
LINK.s = $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_MACH)
```

I see that for assembler sources **TARGET_MACH** is used and for c-sources **TARGET_ARCH** is used but what is the difference and how to correctly specify this variables?

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs210/help/make.html says that `TARGET_ARCH` and `TARGET_MACH` are output of `arch` and `mach` for target system. If you search aforementioned utilities, you can find that on modern systems they corresponds to output of `uname -m` and `uname -p`. For my desktop they give me `x86_64` and `i386` correspondently.

Comment: Both are "The machine architecture of the target system" so it is still not clear. Thanks anyway.